# Multiple routes with same path - use next route (e.g. feature toggle, a/b testing)

Tags: nestjs

does anybody know if there is an option to implement multiple routes in nestjs with the same path.

Lets say:

- /checkout in BasketControllerNew
- /checkout in BasketController

At the first controller, there is a guard which decides if the user can access the /checkout at BasketControllerNew.
Returning false will throw an ForbiddenException, fine.
If I throw a custom exception, the second route will also not be executed.
Filters seems also not able to jump to the next route.

I want to implement feature toggle functionality.
In this case for example a new checkout process with a completely new controller file.
The new checkout process should be tested by some users for example or can be enabled and disabled by feature toggles.

My preferred behaviour would be to throw a custom exception like DisabledRouteException or something like that which means "please try the next matching route".

Another possible usecase could be:

- A cms with a wildcard route which tries to find pages because they do not have a specific prefix at their path
- There will be a module which uses routes prefixed with moduleA/.
- As long as the module is not enabled for a specific customer, the moduleA/* should be handled by the wildcard route because there can be pages at this path.

Has anybody an idea how to implement such things?

Thanks a lot for your support and keep healthy.
Daxi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, which works for me:

**Summary:**

- Multiple routes with same path
- Guard which throws a Exception
- Filter which catches the exception and executes the next route.

**Example code for controller:**

```
@Controller()
export class TestController {
  @Get()
  @UseGuards(TestGuard)
  getHello(): string {
    return "Hello";
  }

  @Get()
  @UseGuards(TestGuard)
  getHello2(): string {
    return "Hello2";
  }

  @Get()
  getHello3(): string {
    return "Hello3";
  }
}
```

**Example code for guard:**

```
@Injectable()
export class TestGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    // add logic here to switch between execution or skip
    throw new NotFoundException('Module not active');
  }
}
```

**Example code for filter:**

```
@Catch(NotFoundException)
export class TestFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: NotFoundException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const next = ctx.getNext();
    next();
  }
}
```

**Enable the filter globaly in main.ts:**

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(TestModule);
  app.useGlobalFilters(new TestFilter());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

To get a proper handling, the code can be improved by generating a custom exception and filter only that, currently all 404s will trigger the next route.

At this example the guard will always throw the exception which ends up at this behaviour:

- guard for getHello will throw the NotFoundException
- filter will trigger the next route
- guard for getHello2 will throw also the NotFoundException
- filter will again trigger the next route
- getHello3 will be executed (no guard active)

My code is only a small POC which can be improved as described and should be improved.
The test was only a very small quick and dirty solution, but if you will need a similar solution, now you can start at the same point.

Kind regards,
Daxi